# How to create a new template instance in Polymer 1.0?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

In Polymer 0.5 I used the templateElement.createInstance(dataToBind) to create a new instance of a template and bind the data object to the new instance:

```
var instance = templateElement.createInstance(dataToBind);
container.appendChild(instance);
```

In Polymer.Base I found the instanceTemplate function to create a new instance of the template, but this function does not bind the data to the instance.
Is there a way to achieve this in Polymer 1.0 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you define a template like this:

```
<template is="dom-template">
  <h2>{{name}}</h2>
  <h3>...lives<h3>
</template>
```

you can generate an instance like this:

```
<script>
  // construct the anonymous presenter
  var instance = templateInstance.stamp();
  // the data model lives on the presenter
  instance.name = 'Instance';
  // the nodes are available in `root`
  document.body.appendChild(instance.root);
</script>
```

This is more or less what happens when you instance a Polymer element, except the presenter is the instance of your element (instead of an anonymous object).